# Tor functor on projective group

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, functors

Why $Tor(A,B)=0$ if either $A$ or $B$ is projective group?
And what exactly is $Tor$ functor? I've read some about $Ext$ and it was more clear for me, how the $Ext$ works and how it is connected with $Hom$, I know that $Tor$ is the same for $\otimes$ but I can't see what exactly it is?

Answer (score 4):

$\text{Tor}^n(A, B)$ can be understood as either the $n^{th}$ right [derived functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_functor) of the functor $A \otimes (-)$, applied to $B$, or as the $n^{th}$ right derived functor of the functor $(-) \otimes B$, applied to $A$. This means, among other things, that for $n \ge 1$ it vanishes if either of these functors is exact, meaning that if $A, B$ are modules then it vanishes if either $A$ or $B$ is [flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module).

Now it's an exercise to show that projective modules are flat. You can do this by showing 1) that free modules are flat and 2) that a retract of a flat module is flat.

Comment: The exactly analogous argument for Ext shows that $\text{Ext}^n(A, B)$ vanishes for $n \ge 1$ if either $A$ is projective or $B$ is injective. But stating the corresponding property for Tor in terms of projectivity is misleading; the natural level of generality is flatness.

Comment: In my book I have clearly explain what is $Ext$ functor; $Ext(A,G)$ is the cokernel of the map $0\rightarrow Hom(A,G)\rightarrow Hom(A,I)\rightarrow Hom(A,J)$. 

About torsion product it's written that for projective resolution $0\rightarrow R\rightarrow F\rightarrow A\rightarrow 0$ we get the exact sequence $0\rightarrow Tor(A,B)\rightarrow R\otimes B\rightarrow F\otimes B\rightarrow A\otimes B\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Moreover any exact sequence $0\rightarrow A'\rightarrow A\rightarrow A''\rightarrow$ induces: $0\rightarrow Tor(A',B)\rightarrow Tor(A,B)\rightarrow Tor(A'',B)\rightarrow A'\otimes B\rightarrow A\otimes B\rightarrow A''\otimes B\rightarrow0$. And suddenly after those facts it is written that "clearly $Tor(A,B)=0$ if $A$ or $B$ is projective." For me it sounds like conclusion of above text, but I don't understand how the $Tor$ works ($Ext$ was explain better for me)